# How to Wait response from Server in forEach with Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I recently started working with coroutines.

The task is that I need to check the `priority` parameter from the List and make a `request` to the server, if the response from the server is OK, then stop the loop.

```
var minPriority = 0
list.forEach { model -> 
   if (model.priority > minPriority) {
       makeRequest(model.value)
       minPriority = model.priority
   }
}

private fun makeRequest(value: String) {
    scope.launch() {
        val response = restApi.makeRequest()
        if response.equals("OK") {
            **stop list foreach()**
        }
    }
}
```

In RxJava, this was done using the `retryWhen()` operator, tell me how to implement this in `Coroutines`?

Comment: What is your main concern here? One thing is that you need to stop the loop from the inner function and this problem is not at all related to coroutines. One solution is to return `Boolean` from `makeRequest()`. Another problem is that you execute the code in `makeRequest()` asynchronously, but you designed the code in the way that it needs to be synchronous. What is the reason you use `scope.launch()` there? I ask because the solution depends on this.

Comment: I only use `scope.launch()` because I don't know any other options yet

Comment: Any other options to solve what problem exactly? You mean `restApi.makeRequest()` is a suspend function, so you can't call it directly? Or you run this code from UI thread and you need to avoid blocking it? Maybe both? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Yes, `restApi.makeRequest()` is a suspend function, and I can't call it directly and it call from UI Thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making your whole code suspendable, not only the body of `makeRequest()` function. This way you can run the whole operation in the background, but internally it will be sequential which is easier to code and maintain.

It could be something like this:

```
scope.launch() {
    var minPriority = 0
    list.forEach { model ->
        if (model.priority > minPriority) {
            val response = restApi.makeRequest()
            if response.equals("OK") {
                return@forEach
            }
            minPriority = model.priority
        }
    }
}
```

Of if you need to keep your `makeRequest()` function separate:

```
fun myFunction() {
    scope.launch() {
        var minPriority = 0
        list.forEach { model ->
            if (model.priority > minPriority) {
                if (makeRequest(model.value)) {
                    return@forEach
                }
                minPriority = model.priority
            }
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun makeRequest(value: String): Boolean {
    val response = restApi.makeRequest()
    return response.equals("OK")
}
```